# Save the IP of a domain to a txt file/Save my dynamic ip to a txt file with c++ or batch

Tags: c++, networking, batch-file, ip, hosts

^^^^

I need to save the IP of my domain (xxx.noip.com) or my external IP to a text file. It will then be uploaded to a public dropbox account.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: My level of knowledge of batch and c++ is at bare minimum. Sorry if I haven't left any examples or etc...

Comment: Open a file, write your IP in it, upload it.

Comment: Automatically? I have a dynamic IP which changes every 10 minutes or so

Comment: @user1924602 - please incorporate your comments into the question to make it more concrete and clear. This will help you get better answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get your external IP by browsing to http://checkip.dyndns.org

**Assuming** your DropBox folder is **C:\dropbox**

Here is a batch script that saves your public ip to a file in your dropbox folder.

**get_my_public_ip.bat:**

```
wget -q -O - http://checkip.dyndns.org > C:\dropbox\my_public_ip.html
```

You will need [wget](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wget) for it to run and it should be placed in a folder that is in your [PATH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28variable%29) variable (e.g. C:\Windows). You can find a windows port [here](http://users.ugent.be/~bpuype/wget/wget.exe). HTML tags are not removed from the file so its contents would be something like:

`<html><head><title>Current IP Check</title></head><body>Current IP Address: 1.2.3.4</body></html>`

Here is a Windows PowerShell script that does the same job **AND strips** the unnecessary text.

**get_my_public_ip.ps1:**

```
(new-object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('http://checkip.dyndns.org')|% { $_ -replace '.*Current IP Address: ([0-9\.]+).*','$1' } > C:\dropbox\my_public_ip.txt
```

Check [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176949.aspx) for some help on how to run Windows PowerShell Scripts.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Here is a script that will do just that.  Set up an automated task with cron to update the ip.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Script to write external ip to ip.txt in Dropbox folder
curl icanhazip.com >> ~/Dropbox/ip.txt
echo "The Ip for $HOSTNAME" >> ~/Dropbox/ip.txt
date >> ~/Dropbox/ip.txt
echo "" >> ~/Dropbox/ip.txt
```